# Open one tab as floating windows in tab-less mode

Tags: intellij-idea

I have watched [03 Mouseless Driven Development by Hadi Hariri](http://vimeo.com/98922030) and switched off tabs. In general it works great, but I have found one issue. I'm working with 2 external monitors. I want to open one class in IntelliJ for editing and open another class from the same project on second monitor. When I'm using tabs I can do floating tabs by dragging tab outside IntelliJ.

Can I achieve similar result with tab-less IntelliJ?

Comment: I don't see a problem using tabs. Using alt-arrow I can switch between tabs rapidly without using a mouse and without interrupting my workflow.

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27072579/1354590

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intellij idea, detach editor window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27045487/intellij-idea-detach-editor-window)