# IntelliJ IDEA - detach editor window

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, editor, intellij-13, intellij-14

I have recently removed tabs from my IntelliJ setup, because with all the features available to navigate between files, who needs them?

The issue is, the normal way of detaching an editor window would be to drag the tab onto another screen (or area). There doesn't appear to be anything in the key mappings for detaching an editor window. Is there a way of doing this via the keyboard?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25380124/open-one-tab-as-floating-windows-in-tab-less-mode

Comment: No, not to my knowledge. You can split vertically or horizontally, or you can navigate via tabs. Or you can run a second session of intellij with its own project and its own frame.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The keyboard shortcut your are looking for is <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> (the action assigned to this shortcut is called *Open Source in New Window*. When you invoke this action the currently opened tab (file) will be opened in new editor window. However the file will remain opened in the main window too, but I believe that this is as close as you can get to the functionality you describe, at least for now.

### Option 2

Open the "Open class" dialog using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> search for a class you want to open in detached window and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>. That will open the class in a new editor window.

Unfortunately this seems to work only for Java classes and not for other files (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> dialog). I created a [bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-133371) for the last problem, so if you think it might be useful, feel free to vote for it.

Comment: A third option: in the Project tab, highlight a file and press shift+enter.

Comment: [Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-code-editor.html?keymap=primary_gnome#detach_tab) you can reach the related official documentation